# Is it possible to set the max size of individual messages when creating a Service Bus queue through PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, pipeline, servicebus

I have a custom task in an Azure DevOps release pipeline that creates topics and queues. It works but giving the PowerShell script a list of the queues or topics to be made, that the script then uses to set everything up on an existing Azure Service Bus.

I recently had to set up a Service Bus with queues that could handle messages up to 100MB, but couldn't find a way to make the script support this. I ended up having to change message sizes manually for all new queues, which was tedious.

Looking online, I still can't find a way to change max message sizes when setting up queues through script. Am I missing something, or is this not possible?

I've looked several places online without finding anything helpful. Most links refer to setting the max queue size, which is not what I'm after. I need to set the max size for the messages themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-MaxMessageSizeInKilobytes` parameter for the `Set-AzServiceBusQueue` CmdLet to specify a maximum message size in a ServiceBus Queue.

```
Set-AzServiceBusQueue -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -NamespaceName myNamespace -Name myQueue -MaxMessageSizeInKilobytes 100
```

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicebus/set-azservicebusqueue?view=azps-9.3.0) for details.